# duplicate keys on multiple drop down buttons

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a search functionality where I have to give the user the leverage to dynamically add search parameters that are in a drop down box.This i am doing using a jquery clone.

Now I also have to make sure that the user does not select the same search criteria twice and hence to prevent that, I have to disable the selected options.

My attempt to do this fails when there are more than two dropdowns

http://jsfiddle.net/V8uFE/

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Raj

Comment: I need this for a search functionality, so there would be input fields against each criteria, something like http://jsfiddle.net/bWN7L/

Answer (score 0):

instead you can use multiple select in single list itself..But if you want to do that you can use AJAX for this.

Comment: I need this for a search functionality, so there would be input fields against each criteria, something like http://jsfiddle.net/bWN7L/

Comment: ok ok ... So you could use AJAX and keep ignoring the values that you hav already selected.. Go through some ajax tutorial..That will help you implementing things

Comment: I am ignoring them, as a matter of fact overwriting them with new occurrences but I need a front end validation to tell the user that he has selected the same criteria twice. It's kind of a requirement

Answer (score 0):

check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8uFE/3/).

coloring works. but not disabled property. you have to investigate that.

you can use like this instead of change coloring.

```
if(flag)               
    $(this).css('display','none');               
else               
    $(this).css('display', 'block');
```

i think disabled property also triggers change event. i am not sure about that. but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code, i think ishould help you in some way!!

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<script>
        function disableValue(str){
                    var dis1=document.getElementsByTagName("option");
                     for(var i=0;i<dis1.length;i++){
                            if(dis1[i].value==str){
                                 dis1[i].disabled=true;
                            }
                     }
                    return true;
        }

    </script>
<body>

   <select  onchange="return disableValue(this.value)">
<option selected="selected">-Search Parameters-</option>
<option value="1" class="go1">1</option>
<option value="2" class="go2">2</option>
<option value="3" class="go3">3</option>
</select>

<select onchange="return disableValue(this.value)">
<option selected="selected">-Search Parameters-</option>
<option value="1" class="go1">1</option>
<option value="2" class="go2">2</option>
<option value="3" class="go3">3</option>
</select>

<select onchange="return disableValue(this.value)">
<option selected="selected">-Search Parameters-</option>
<option value="1" class="go1">1</option>
<option value="2" class="go2">2</option>
<option value="3" class="go3">3</option>
</select>

<div id="work"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```